# Networking function expects delegate, passing it but says unknown member

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a simple client-server communication between a Node.js server and an Unity Android game, but I'm having problems trying to figure out why the code I'm making doesn't work.

In the game, I'm using the .NET Socket class, as required functionality is very simple, but when passing a function called "ReceiveData" to the function BeginReceive (this function expects a delegate), it throws an error. But when debugging, it says that the function "ReceiveData" is an unknown member, but it's there!!! The image shows the code fragment and this strange bug.

May somebody help me figuring out what to do to fix the problem, or explain to me what is happening. I've searched a lot for similar problems in this and other forums, but came out unsuccessful.

---

[image: Monodevelop image]

### [image: Code fragment image (consulta.png)]

```
public class AccountManager : Singleton<AccountManager>
{
    [...]

    private void Initialize()
    {
        // Configurar conexión
        this.clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp  );  
        this.clientSocket.Connect(AccountManager.serverAddress, AccountManager.port);

        // Empezar a recibir datos
        this.clientSocket.BeginReceive(this.receivedDataBuffer, 0, this.receivedDataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                                       this.ReceiveData, null);
    }

    private void ReceiveCommand(string command) {...}

    public void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        // Comprobar longitud de respuesta
        int responseLength = this.clientSocket.EndReceive(asyncResult);
        if (responseLength <= 0) return;

        // Copiar datos recibidos en array local
        byte[] responseData = new byte[responseLength];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(this.receivedDataBuffer, 0, responseData, 0, responseLength);

        // Procesar datos
        this.ReceiveCommand(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseData));

        // Empezar a recibir otra vez
        this.clientSocket.BeginReceive(this.receivedDataBuffer, 0, this.receivedDataBuffer.Length,
            SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveData), null);
    }

    private void SendCommand(string command) {...}

    private void Awake()
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        this.clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        this.clientSocket.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of error did you get? Can you show us its details? As for that 'unknown member' note, it's probably because your debugger only shows fields and properties. If that really were a problem your code would not have been compiled in the first place.

Comment: Not 100% on this so I don't want to post it as the answer but the mdsn always uses the `new AsyncCallback()` method. Try this `this.clientSocket.BeginReceive(this.receivedDataBuffer, 0, this.receivedDataBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                                       new AsyncCallback(this.ReceiveData), null);`

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work too. I've added a try-catch block surrounding the code of the Initialize method, and when debugging, something curious happens: First tries to execute the BeginReceive method, then jumps to the catch block, then jumps to the end of Initialize without entering the catch block... It's very weird IMO @_@

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem.

I'm now using the class System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient, which is easier to use and more reliable.

```
this.tcpClient = new TcpClient();
this.tcpClient.Connect(/*Enter address and port*/);

this.networkStream = this.tcpClient.GetStream();
this.streamReader = new StreamReader(this.networkStream);
this.streamWriter = new StreamWriter(this.networkStream);
```

This way allows easy communication by using streams.